# What is the fastest way to check if a sentence contains items in a list?

Tags: python, performance

There is a file with 90,000+ lines and a list (called "entity_list") with 40,000+ entities. I am trying to identify if a line contains items in the list. If yes, locating items' locations (start position: "start", end position: "end") and replacing them with "new_item"

I have tried two for-loop operations. I use regular expressions to locate items, but it is not shown in the following code.

```py
for line in file.readlines():
    for entity in entity_list:
        if entity in line:
             line = line.replace(line[start:end], new_item)
```

However, it is really slow. Is it a faster way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compile your entity list into regex and try `re.subn`. @DYZ I think it's very much not ideal to use an embedded loop.

Comment: @knh190 Rather, `re.sub`.

Comment: But regex covering 40000+ items can be hard. You may still need multiple regexes.

Comment: `celery` -- I think you can convert the file to a dict as {line_index: line_content}, then add every line as a task to celery. After all tasks done, join lines to be a new file.

Comment: @WaketZheng Do you mean to split the file into sentences and parallelly replace them?

Comment: You can probably save some time if you convert you entity_list to a set and use `if any(s in line for s in entity_set)`..

Comment: @Sirui Li Where are you getting the new_item from?

Comment: @SiruiLi Yes. multiprocessing or celery.  parallelly .

Comment: @Vishnudev The new_item is just to replace space with "_" in the entity. For example, the entity is "python 3.6.8", the new item would be "python_3.6.8".

Comment: @HenryYik If using "any", I cannot locate entities.

Comment: From your code you were not replacing entity with anything. In the future, it will be possible to locate `entities` with [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target) in Python 3.8. For now you can still use a `set` though.

Comment: Try a look at this: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html